# how can i fix the picture box in C#

Tags: c#, picturebox

i have 16 picture box in my form design in C# form , and i should choose two random number and put a specific picture on the box related to these random numbers , for example i have two random number like these 8 ,13 and a picture should be put at these places.

for this i write this code:

```
            Random rnd = new Random();

            int p1 = rnd.Next(1, 17);

            int p2 = rnd.Next(1, 17);

            pcbxp1.BackgroundImage=Image.FromFile(@"C:location\22.jpg");
```

i know this code has error because i call my places like this , pcbx(1.....16)
and for putting image on it i sholud write like this for example :

```
      pcbx1.BackgroundImage=Image.FromFile(@"C:\location\22.jpg");
```

and pcbxp1 is wrong (p1 is the first random number)
how can i put image for picturebox related to random numbers?

Comment: You need to put the picture boxes in an array or a List<>, then you can access them via their index. But please supply eg. a screenshot to make it clear what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)this.Controls.Find("pcbx" + p1, true)[0];
pb.BackgroundImage=Image.FromFile(@"C:\location\22.jpg");
```

By using this.Controls.Find, we can find a control on page.

Comment: I am still learning new things daily.  My answer would have been like in a comment above, to put the picture boxes in a List and select that way.  Somehow I made it all this time without realizing there was a Controls.Find method in the Framework.  Very cool.

Comment: @apdi this.Controls means it gives all the controls. this.Controls.Find("ID you want to find") will return an array. So I used [0] to get the first one and saving it in a PictureBox pb. So I am casting an object in array to PictureBox type. Now you can perform all PictureBox operations on pb. Hope this is clear.